# Running Filebeat in Kubernetes with persistent registry file?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, filebeat, persistent-storage

If a container running filebeat is lost and we launch a new container, the registry file of the old container will be lost too and the new container wouldn't know from where the harvester should read the new files which will cause inconsistent/ambiguous data in elasticsearch. It will read the whole file again. So, how should I go with creating a consistent registry file?

Should I also mount `/var/lib/filebeat/` to some persistent volume?

Right now, I am thinking in kubernetes(AWS EKS) context. I have a persistent volume(AWS EFS). I have created a `pvc`(persistent volume claim) for each application, lets say `app1-pvc` for app1. This `pvc` is mounted to `/var/log/app1/` location both on application and filebeat container. Filebeat is reading input from the file `/var/log/app1/api_info.log`. So, if my filebeat container gets restarted, the registry file will be lost and the whole api_info will be read again.

Am I thinking in the right way? If yes, then what are the ways to avoid the scenario which I'm facing here? If no, how does it prevent the above scenario? Or where I'm thinking wrong?

Comment: have to you tried to deploy filebeat with `hostPathRoot` option? there you can specify a _hostPath_ that will be used to persist Filebeat registry data.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays probably the most straightforward way in kubernetes is to use the [ECK operator](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/index.html) and the [native `Beat` CRD support for filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-beat.html). As of today, you can find examples in the official docs [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-beat-configuration-examples.html).

When deploying e.g. this:

```yaml
apiVersion: beat.k8s.elastic.co/v1beta1
kind: Beat
metadata:
  name: filebeat
spec:
  type: filebeat
  version: 7.16.2
  ...
  daemonSet:
    podTemplate:
      spec:
        serviceAccountName: filebeat
        ...
        containers:
          - name: filebeat
          ...
```

filebeat will be deployed as a `DaemonSet` and will by default use a host directory for the state files, so the it will survive between restarts.

As you can see on the [current implementation of the ECK controller](https://github.com/elastic/cloud-on-k8s/blob/d7a42645aa05618e15f2924159304ee12534ddfc/pkg/controller/beat/common/pod.go#L30), it will create a host volume under `/var/lib/<beat-namespace>/<beat-name>/<beat-type>-data`

```golang
    DataMountPathTemplate = "/var/lib/%s/%s/%s-data"
...
func createDataVolume(dp DriverParams) volume.VolumeLike {
    dataMountPath := fmt.Sprintf(DataPathTemplate, dp.Beat.Spec.Type)
    hostDataPath := fmt.Sprintf(DataMountPathTemplate, dp.Beat.Namespace, dp.Beat.Name, dp.Beat.Spec.Type)

    return volume.NewHostVolume(
        DataVolumeName,
        hostDataPath,
        dataMountPath,
        false,
        corev1.HostPathDirectoryOrCreate)
}
```

In my case I'm storing all ECK resources on namespace `elastic-system` with k3s and those files end up with state files stored in host directory `/var/lib/elastic-system/filebeat/filebeat-data/`.